# JScrollPane not showing up

Tags: java, jscrollpane

So I am making a list of names of the players that have previously played the games. I came across the problem that the list is not adding a scroll pane to it after the names list becomes way too long without scrolling. I have tried to implement the scroll bar this way but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Insets insets = pane.getInsets();

    Dimension size = Player1.getPreferredSize();

    Player1.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 50 + insets.top, 250, 40);
        size = Player2.getPreferredSize();
    Player2.setBounds(450 + insets.left, 50 + insets.top, 250, 40);
        size = P1List.getPreferredSize();
    P1List.setBounds(90 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top, 250, 350);
        size = P2List.getPreferredSize();
    P2List.setBounds(450 + insets.left, 100 + insets.top, 250, 350);
    Ok.setBounds(650 + insets.left, 500 + insets.top, 100, 30);
        size = Ok.getPreferredSize();

    final JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
    sp1.setViewportView(P1List);

    final JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane();
    sp2.setViewportView(P2List);

    pane.add(Player1);
    pane.add(Player2);
    pane.add(P1List);
    pane.add(P2List);
    pane.add(sp1);
    pane.add(sp2);
    pane.add(Ok);
```

Comment: do not add `P1List` and `P2List` to the `pane`

Comment: what do you mean? How else should I do it?

Comment: You have already added `P1List` and `P2List` to `sp1` and `sp2`. Therefore not need of adding them again to the `pane`.. Any way, what is `pane`..? A `JPanel`..?

Comment: pane is a container. Also I tried what you told me, but the JLists completely disappeared!

Comment: Just add `P1List` and `P2List` to `sp1` and `sp2`. Do not set bounds of them. Instead, set bounds of `sp1` and `sp2`

Comment: That did not work either. The JLists are there but they don't have anything inside of them.

Comment: Found out the problem. Found out that I declared the JSrollPane as a final attribute and also did what @Ramesh-x said.